# How to repeat the columns based on the json data for datatable display

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Hi I have a JSON data coming from AJAX response and it has nested array.

```
[{
    "Solution": "MobileBroadband",
    "Operator": "MTN",
    "VNF": [{
        "vendor": "vendor1",
        "name": "product1",
        "release": "1.0"
    },
    {
        "vendor": "vendor3",
        "name": "prodc3",
        "release": "3.0"
    },
    {
        "vendor": "saef",
        "name": "vEPG",
        "release": "2.4"
    }]
},
{
    "Solution": "CLoud",
    "Operator": "Airtel",
    "VNF": [{
        "vendor": "vendor1",
        "name": "product1",
        "release": "1.0"
    },
    {
        "vendor": "vendor3",
        "name": "prodc3",
        "release": "3.0"
    }]
}]
```

How can I dynamically add the above data to columns of data table.

I am expecting something like this:

[image]

Comment: Just in case, your JSON is invalid (it has missing commas and double quotes around property keys).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you would need to set DataTables [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option accordingly:

```
$('#mytable').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        ...
        url: '/getdata' //URL to API that returns your JSON data
    }

});
```

Next, you need to 'flatten' your source JSON structure, so that it contains array of objects where each property corresponds to table column. For that purpose, you may need to use [`ajax.dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option (to postprocess received JSON):

```
$('#mytable').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: '/getdata',
        dataSrc: rawJson => rawJson.map(entry => {
            entry.VNF.forEach((vnfEntry, vnfEntryIndex) => Object.entries(vnfEntry).forEach(vnfEntryProp => entry[vnfEntryProp[0] + vnfEntryIndex] = vnfEntryProp[1]));
            delete entry.VNF;
            return entry;
        })
    }
});
```

And finally, you may want to suppress DataTables warning that informs you about missing data for certain columns (as you have different number of NFV vendors for different operators):

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'none';
```

But you must be carefull with that option as it will suppress **all** error notifications from DataTables engine.

For full-blown **demo**, you might want to check out this [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/m9q0kor3wp?fontsize=14).

Comment: Thanks..This works but only thing is i have a column no of vnf's and based on that how can i iterate through the vnfName,vendor and release instead of giving {title: 'vnf-vendor', data: 'vendor0'},
            {title: 'vnf-name', data: 'name0'},
            {title: 'vnf-release', data: 'release0'},
            {title: 'vnf-vendor', data: 'vendor1'},
            {title: 'vnf-name', data: 'name1'},
            {title: 'vnf-release', data: 'release1'},

Comment: Than you may go, like (assuming 3 is a maximum number of vendors): `['Solution', 'Operator'].map(item => ({title:item, data: item})).concat([...Array(3)].map((iter, iterIndex) => ['vendor','name','release'].map(item => ({title: 'vnf-'+item, data: item+iterIndex}))).flat())`

Comment: Haa..I am not able to get it..if you dont mind can you update in the demo link u provided.

Also i will be having other columns after this VNF.So in that case i think i cant give Concat right.?

Comment: Nothing special: I map common property names ('Solution', 'Operator') into array of objects `[{title: ...., header: ...}, {...}]` and append to that array (`.concat()`) similar mapping of repeating (3 times) properties 'vendor, 'name', 'release'. I've updated the demo.

Comment: @srilakshmi : so, have you succeeded in solving your problem? If my answer and comments did help, you may upvote and accept this answer.

Comment: HI,I could not..because the data i am getting si little different.

I have posted a new question.Can you pls check and let me know if u can help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55739931/how-to-convert-semicolon-seperated-data-in-array-to-columns-in-datatable

Comment: Well, my code above, apparently, solves the issue you have described in *this* post with the data, you have provided in *this* post, producing exactly the output you have described. I even optimized the code after you commented 'Thanks. This works...'. So, if we may consider **this** particular issue closed (upvote and accept would be perfect) I will gladly look into your (entirely) different question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your response like this:

```
var data = [
    [ "Row 1 - Field 1", "Row 1 - Field 2", "Row 1 - Field 3" ],
    [ "Row 2 - Field 1", "Row 2 - Field 2", "Row 2 - Field 3" ],
];

var columns = [
    { "title":"One" },
    { "title":"Two" },
    { "title":"Three" }
];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: "Bfrtip",
    data: data,
    columns: columns
  });
});
```

You can try this in js fiddle