# How to render the nested json into a datatable column

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am new to datatables and i am trying to display the data from json to Datatable dynamically.

Below is the nested json.

```html
{
  Solution: "MobileBroadband",
  Operator: "MTN"
  
  VNF: [
    {
      "vendor": "vendor1",
      "name": "product1",
      "release": "1.0"
    },
    {
      "vendor": "vendor3",
      "name": "prodc3",
      "release": "3.0"
    },
    {
     
      "vendor": "saef",
      "name": "vEPG",
      "release": "2.4"
    }
  ]
 },
{
  Solution: "CLoud",
  Operator: "Airtel"`enter code here`
  
  VNF: [
    {
      "vendor": "vendor1",
      "name": "product1",
      "release": "1.0"
    },
    {
      "vendor": "vendor3",
      "name": "prodc3",
      "release": "3.0"
    }    
  ]
 },
```

I am expecting the output to be something like this.

Expected result[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NJWz.png)

Comment: I would recommend avoid posting the same questions, it won't increase to get your chances to get the answer. So, please, delete your question and check out my reply to your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55702614/how-to-repeat-the-columns-based-on-the-json-data-for-datatable-display/55708730#55708730)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to repeat the columns based on the json data for datatable display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55702614/how-to-repeat-the-columns-based-on-the-json-data-for-datatable-display)