# How to convert semicolon delimited data into separate lines within DataTable cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have an array within JSON document. Below is one item from that array:

```
{
    "generalSolution": "Cloud",
    "generalOperator": "MTN",
    "genericCountry": "USA",
    "vnfProductName": "vEPG;vSAPC;vSGSN-MME",
    "vnfRelease": "2.4;1.3;v1.2399999",
    "vnfVendor": "Ericsson;Ericsson;Ericsson"
}
```

I would like to display the data in DataTables as a single row, like this:

[image]

Note, that vnf details (`vnfProductName`, `vnfRelease`, `vnfVendor`) can have variable number of entries.

Comment: For jquery is very nice datatable plugin: https://www.datatables.net/ but this table view is also simple -.6 <td> per one <tr> of data.

Comment: @Zydnar:Thanks for the idea.But i dont want to display in this manner as later i have to convert the datatable to excel where it will give problem

Comment: @srilakshmi : As far as I know, there's no common delimiter understood as a 'new line' by both Excel and HTML, so exporting into Excel with semicolons brought back in place, could possibly be achieved, using `format.body` option of [`buttons.exportData()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons.exportData()) API method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/renderer) option to transform your data upon rendering:

```js
//use JSON excerpt as a data source
var srcData = [{
    "generalSolution": "Cloud",
    "generalOperator": "MTN",
    "genericCountry": "USA",
    "vnfProductName": "vEPG;vSAPC;vSGSN-MME",
    "vnfRelease": "2.4;1.3;v1.2399999",
    "vnfVendor": "Ericsson;Ericsson;Ericsson"
}];

//initialize DataTables
const dataTables = $('#mytable').DataTable({
  data: srcData,
  dom: 't',
  //map all property keys (assuming, set of properties is uniform for all array entries)
  //into array, expected by 'columns' option: [{title: ..., data: ...}...]
  columns: Object.keys(srcData[0]).map(propertyKey => ({title: propertyKey, data: propertyKey})),
  //use additionally 'columnDefs' option to apply 'render' callback to certain columns
  columnDefs: [{
    targets: [3, 4, 5],
    //replace semicolons in each cell contents within columns 3, 4, 5 with new line tag `<br>`
    render: (data, type, row, meta) => data ? data.replace(/;/g, '<br>') : ''
  }]
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<table id="mytable"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks..this helps...At the same time can i do something like this.

{
                 "data": "vnfVendor",    
                 render: (data, type, row, meta) => data.replace(/;/g, '<br>')
                 
             }, {
                 "data": "vnfProductName",
                 render: (data, type, row, meta) => data.replace(/;/g, '<br>')
              
             }, {
                 "data": "vnfRelease",
                 render: (data, type, row, meta) => data.replace(/;/g, '<br>')
             },

Comment: Yes, you can, but is there a reason you would need to do that instead of using one common rendering function for all target columns (like it is done in my example)?

Comment: @srilakshmi : And, to your consideration, my solution has slight advantage over another answer - event though we use essentially the same method, I've integrated my code into `render` option which will work regardless of the data source. Another answer will require wrap 'replacing' block into another iterator to loop through entire array and then put that into `ajax.success` or `ajax.dataSrc` option if AJAX-source is used (which is the case, as I understand).

Comment: Becuase i have some more code like this.

defs = [{
            "targets": '_all',
            "visible": true,
            "orderable" : true 
        },

So instead of all when i gave the columnnumbers,it was displaying only those three columns.
So i wanted to try this way

Comment: That is why, `columnDefs` expects an array of objects, thus, you can do `[{targets:[3,4,5],render:(data,type,row,meta)=>data.replace(/;/g,'<br>')},{"targets":'_all',"visible":true,"orderable":true}]`

Comment: :Also if i have only one value at times that is no semicolon at all..its throwing an error.So i have to put a condition right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192037/discussion-between-sri-lakshmi-and-user11299053).

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace `;` by `<br>` with [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/replace).

*This is an example. Here, the original object is altered. Think to adapt id if needed.*

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  const obj = {
    "generalSolution": "Cloud",
    "generalOperator": "MTN",
    "genericCountry": "USA",
    "vnfProductName": "vEPG;vSAPC;vSGSN-MME",
    "vnfRelease": "2.4;1.3;v1.2399999",
    "vnfVendor": "Ericsson;Ericsson;Ericsson"
  };

  for (let key in obj) {
    // Here!
    obj[key] = obj[key].replace(/;/g, '<br>');
  }
  
  $('#dt').DataTable({
    data: [obj],
    columns: [
      {data: 'generalSolution'},
      {data: 'generalOperator'},
      {data: 'genericCountry'},
      {data: 'vnfProductName'},
      {data: 'vnfRelease'},
      {data: 'vnfVendor'}
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="dt">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>generalSolution</th>
      <th>generalOperator</th>
      <th>genericCountry</th>
      <th>vnfProductName</th>
      <th>vnfRelease</th>
      <th>vnfVendor</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```